# autenticar con express + react + redux?

Tags: express, reactjs, redux

alguien me puede recomendar cual es la mejor manera de autenticar con express + react + redux?

no tengo claro si usar passport o json token?

a quien a podido protejer api con express!

Answer (score 1):

Despues de buscar informacion de cual es la manera mas adecuada de autenticar react, encontre este exelente tutorial que despejo toda mis dudas!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyyPUIAe6kc&index=18&list=PLuNEz8XtB51K-x3bwCC9uNM_cxXaiCcRY

en la que se usa JWT (json web token) 
dejo la solucion a mi pregunta por si depronto le puede ayudar a alguien!

link del repositorio del tutorial
https://github.com/Remchi/reddice